# Export python folium heat map with time to html

Tags: python, html, export, heatmap, folium

I have a HeatMapWithTime created with the folium library. The heatmap changes over time. I want to export this map into an HTML in a dynamic format. I want to use this map for presentations without having to run the code. Please I would appreciate it if someone can show me how to export my map without losing the time step.

My map code:

```
map_Oslo = folium.Map(location=[Latitude, Longitude], zoom_start=5)
plugins.HeatMapWithTime(heat_data, 
                        radius=10,
                gradient={0.1: 'blue', 0.2: 'blue', 0.4: 'lime', 0.6: 'orange', 0.8: 'red', 0.99: 'purple'},
                min_opacity=0.5, max_opacity=0.8, use_local_extrema=False).add_to(map_Oslo)
map_Oslo
```

[image]

I tried some suggestions but I get the error `WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`and I can not tell if the code works.
:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver

delay=5
fn='testmap.html'
tmpurl='file://{path}/{mapfile}'.format(path=os.getcwd(),mapfile=fn)
map_Oslo.save(fn)

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(tmpurl)
#Give the map tiles some time to load
time.sleep(delay)
browser.save_screenshot('map.png')
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 6):

**Try this simple solution:**

```
map_Oslo.save("heat_map.html")
```